# Batch Copy Rename, Prompt on duplicate

Tags: batch-file, duplicates, copy, file-rename

Super new to batch files and programming in general so any help is appriciated;
I'm trying to copy, and rename a file based on user input, then open the new file. My issue is, If there is a duplicate, I want it to re-prompt the user for a different name. Right now I have:

```
SET /P "dname=Type new sheet name, then press Enter:"
COPY "O:\master.xlsx" "O:\%dname%.xlsx" /V /-Y
START /D "O:" %dname%.xlsx
```

And this works for copying and renaming, but if there is a duplicate, I get the prompt 'do you want to copy Y/N' but if I say no, it doesn't ask for a different name.
Thank you!

Edit 1:
I now have this:

```
SET /P "dname=Type sheet name, then press Enter:"
IF EXIST "O:\%dname%.xlsx" (
    :RETRY
    SET /P "dname=Error! There is already a file named %dname%. Please choose a new unique name:"
    IF EXIST "O:\%dname%.xlsx" (
        GOTO :RETRY
        ELSE GOTO :COPY
        )
    ) ELSE GOTO :COPY
:COPY
COPY "O:\master.xlsx" "O:\%dname%.xlsx" /V /-Y
```

And it seems to work reliably. Is there a better way to streamline/optimize this with a loop? Or is that good enough?

Comment: There is no built-in method to do this. You have to write a script for it (featuring [if exist](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) and a method of your choice to generate a unique file name - easiest method would be to increase a counter, like `explorer` does)

Comment: The problem in your new attempt (edit) is that you use a label within a paranthesised block of code, but this does not work; if `goto ::RETRY` runs execution does not "stay" in the block, it treats the target label and everything after as it was outside of a block, where `) else goto :COPY` is not allowed; that is a masty limitation of batch files...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "oldname=master"
:loop
set "newname=%oldname%"
set /p "newname=New Name: "
if exist "%newname%.xlsx" (
  echo %newname%.xlsx already exists. Chose another name.
  goto :loop
)
COPY "%oldname%.xlsx" "%newname%.xlsx"
```